# Json string: check all keys that starts their name with "a string" but have all values empty

Tags: jquery, json

I've got this code but it's not correct

```
    var test_h2s = JSON.parse($.cookie('name_of_cookie'));
JSON.stringify(test_h2s, function(key, value) {
// when encoutering one of the keys we're looking for, with all values empty

while(key.substr(0, 3) === 'h2s' && value !== "") {
//do something

}

});
```

I've to check all keys that starts their name with `h2s` and have all values `empty ("h2s...":"")`
ex. in json after parse(JSON.stringify)
`{"h2s":"on","h2s_perc":"dffdfd","other_Content_Outlet":"fdfd"....ecc...ecc}`

Answer (score 1):

this is the code that will loop over your JSON object and within the IF statement you can access those key/value pairs that have empty values and begin with 'h2s'.

```
var test_h2s = {"h2s":"on","h2s_perc":"dffdfd","other_Content_Outlet":"fdfd","h2s_empty":""};

for (var key in test_h2s) {
    if(key.substr(0,3) === 'h2s' && test_h2s[key] == ""){
        console.log(key); // Prints out the key that has empty value
    };
};
```